# SSRS Chart with Start and End dates on the x axis

Tags: time, charts, reporting-services

Good day,

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to do something like this in SSRS:
[Exampled of the graph I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSUGf.png)

I have the data as follows:
[Graph Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbjRz.png)

I have tried a few suggestions on this group, but this is the closest I can get it to working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acFVp.png)

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I haven't used the Range Chart but it looks like you have the User as the Category and the values. If the Job # was used as the Series, it should look like it you want.